# Can present perfect be used to perform habitual in past?

Tags: present-perfect

I got this quiz from faceb**k group (credit to the owner), here's the sentence:

> **I _______ to school but Ann used to go to school by her bike.**
>
> a) was walking
>
> b) have always walked
>
> c) have walked
>
> d) None of the options a), b), and c) are correct.

I'm not sure which one is correct, but i guess c) is appropriate? Since it's a guess, can you tell me if my answer is correct? I was distracted by "always" and I thought it *may be* related to habitual activity in past.

Comment: Technically speaking, these all can be correct.

Comment: @user178049 Hi, first thanks for the reply. By the way what about the information "used to" in that sentence? Isn't it supposed to be a habitual in past? If i choose a) it would be a past progressive that happens currently in past and just for once time. And c) is like we've done something? I really confused now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little clumsy. The phrase "Ann used to go to school by her bike." isn't what I would say, though it's technically correct.
I would say
"Ann used to go to school by bike." or
"Ann used to bike to school."

Anyway, if this is supposed to be a good sentence that stays on subject, it has to be
I b) have always walked to school but Ann used to bike." It still sounds forced.

a) would imply a change of subject, raising biking as another possibility.

c)would imply walking is an unusual occurrence then changes tracks and starts talking about Ann.

What Ann used to do has nothing to do with what you do now or in the past, so this sounds forced in all cases.
"Ann and I used to bike to school, but she doesn't like to ride anymore." (implies together)

Ann and I walk to school but we used to bike sometimes.

Ann and I mostly walk to school but she used to bike sometimes.

I have always walked to school but Ann used to bike. Now she walks with me. (Or, 'Now we walk together.')